# Nesting Lambda functions - Performance implications

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, lambda, c++14

I have a top level lambda function and then there are couple of nested lambda functions inside this lambda.

Is it a good idea to nest lambdas inside other lambdas? Are there any performance implications?

For e.g.

```
auto Multiplier1 = []() -> int
{
    auto Multiplier2 = [](int i) -> int
    {
        auto Multiplier3 = [](int i) -> int
        {
            return i * 2;
        };
        std::cout << "Calling another lambda 2\n";
        return Multiplier3(i * 100);
    };

    int i = 10;
    std::cout << "Calling another lambda 1\n";
    int ret = Multiplier2(i);
    return ret;
};

int ret = Multiplier1();
std::cout << ret << "\n";
```

In the example above, I can re-factor Multiplier2 and Multiplier3 into separate functions. Is that a better approach compared to this?

I am modifying a code which is already in production and hence, I was in a dilemma whether to re-factor it into separate functions or manage using lambda functions.

Comment: "*Are there any performance implications?*" For captureless lambdas, as you have, absolutely not.

Comment: Honest question: Why not wrap a loop around the canned example you have and time it. Then refactor and time that? As @ildjarn points out you need to be sure the signatures of those lambdas are precisely equivalent to the real lambdas you have in production.

Comment: @Hal You are right. Best thing is to time and check the performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asking about performance implications as a result of expression of coding style is always the wrong question.

The compiler, when optimising, considers *expressed intent*, not the layout of your code.

This example is extreme but it's worth showing you the code produced by gcc with compiler option `-O2`.

Refactoring the code above to remove the noise that will be produced by the use of `cout`:

```
auto Multiplier1 = []() -> int
{
    auto Multiplier2 = [](int i) -> int
    {
        auto Multiplier3 = [](int i) -> int
        {
            return i * 2;
        };
        return Multiplier3(i * 100);
    };

    int i = 10;
    int ret = Multiplier2(i);
    return ret;
};

extern void emit(int);

int main()
{
    int ret = Multiplier1();
    emit(ret);
}
```

compiling with `gcc -S -O2 -std=c++14` yields:

```
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $2000, %edi
        call    emit(int)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Notice that the optimiser has seen through all the code and realised that the only course of action this code could ever take (that matters) is to call the function `emit` with the argument value of 2000.

The lesson is always that one should express intent elegantly (i.e. in a way that can be understood and maintained easily) and allow the compiler to do its job of emitting code that implements that intent in the least time and/or code size.